# TypeError: je.filter is not a function, however `je` seemingly should always be an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

We are receiving a `TypeError: je.filter is not a function` for the line of code below with the `.filter()`. We are very confused as to how the `playerAggPbpStatsNoPctiles` variable, which `je` refers to in the Sentry error, is not an array:

**PlayerStats.js**

```
// fetch data, filter fetched data
const fetchConfig = { ep: 'player-agg-pbp-stats', cfg: { competitionId, teamId } }
const { data: playerAggPbpStatsNoPctiles = [], isLoading: isLoading1, isError: isError1 } = useCBBQuery(fetchConfig);
const playerAggPbpStats = playerAggPbpStatsNoPctiles.filter(row => filterForScope({ row, scope }));
```

**useCBBQuery.js**

```
// wrapper around useQuery for fetching data from our API
const useCBBQuery = ({ ep, routeKey = 'gs', cfg = {}, optionsConfig = {}, refetchKey = 0 }) => {
    // ep:              endpoint
    // routeKey:        the base part of the URL for the route, one of [gs, gsl, users, email, stripe]
    // cfg:             parameters config
    // optionsConfig:   react-query options config
    // refetchKey:      integer that we increment to trigger refetching, add to queryKey array

    // create queryKey, return useQuery using fetchData
    const cfgString = JSON.stringify(cfg);
    const queryKey = [ep, cfgString, refetchKey];
    const isDisabled = cfg && cfg.pass === true;

    // create fetch URL
    let fetchUrl = createUrl(ep, cfg, routeKey);

    // call useQuery
    const query = useQuery({
        queryKey,
        queryFn: () => fetchData({ fetchUrl }),
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        enabled: !isDisabled,
        ...optionsConfig
    });

    return {
        ...query,
        isLoading: query.isLoading && query.fetchStatus !== 'idle'
    };
};
```

We fetch data `playerAggPbpStatsNoPctiles`, using an empty array `[]` as fallback during data fetching. This fetch seemingly should *always* return an array, and 99.9% of the time, an array is properly returned.

We recently added some additional data logged to sentry that shows what the variable is right before it errors out. Here's a screenshot from Sentry:

```
export function sentryIsArray({ arr, page, name }) {
    // array:       variable that should be an array
    if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
        const error = new Error('Input is not an array');
        Sentry.captureException(error, {
            extra: {
                info: `${page} expected an array for ${name}`,
                receivedType: typeof arr,
                receivedValue: arr
            }
        });

        console.error('Expected an array, received:', arr);
    }
}
```

[image]

String?  This looks like an array to me. What could possibly be going on that this variable is seen as a string leading to `.filter is not a function` errors being thrown?

What am I potentially missing here? How can I troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Yes it _"looks like"_ an array, it's JSON. Have you tried _parsing_ it?

Comment: I am not using `JSON.parse()` if that's what you're asking? The value is an array 99.9% of the time, .filter() works almost always, it is simply confusing as to why .filter() doesn't work 0.1% of the time for this code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can i buy you a dozen coffees to help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when something is of type `string` but it looks like an `array`, it is a JSON array.

So, before you run `playerAggPbpStatsNoPctiles.filter()` you might want to check if that value is a `string`, in which case you `JSON.parse` it first.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there any rhyme or reason why `useQuery()` would return an array the majority of the time, but a JSON array on very rare occasion? Size of the data?

Comment: That, I don't know. Not familiar with useQuery/react. You might need to investigate. I doubt that the same query would alternate between js and json arrays if the dataset all use the same. So either the data is stored differently in some cases, or there is a reason why the query produces a different result type in specific situations.